# Update associated field in Waterline/Sails without affecting other fields

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I notice that multiple requests to a record causes writes to be possibly overwritten. I am using Mongo btw.

I have a schema like:

- `Trip { id, status, tagged_friends }`

  - where `tagged_friends` is an association to Users collection

When I make 2 calls to update trips in close succession (in this case I am making 2 API calls from client - actually automated tests), its possible for them to interfere. Since they all call `trip.save()`.

- Update 1: update the `tagged_friends` association
- Update 2: update the `status` field

So I am thinking these 2 updates should only save the "dirty" fields. I think I can do that with `Trips.update()` rather than `trip.save()`? But problem is I cannot use update to update an association? That does not appear to work?

Or perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Comment: "When I make 2 calls to update trips in close succession, its possible for them to interfere :"  can you be more precise about this statement. Do you make 2 calls inside your code or if you make 2 calls on your "client" one after each others ?

Comment: Are you passing the full trip object in both of your API calls ?

Comment: Not really, but the problem is AFAIK, to add/remove things from an association, I will need to use `model.association_field.add/remove` then I need to call `model.save()`. The problem is this save call. It overwrites the all other fields too, even if another user triggered an update